# Article Thumbnail not Showing Up When Sharing via LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to share an article link via LinkedIn API and see it appear on my feed with a thumbnail. It does work when I do it manually on my profile, but using API the thumbnail is not there...

Any ideas on how to work around this? The documentation doesn't really specify anything:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin